# Pardot: progressive profiling for the "above form" text

Tags: forms, webforms, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm looling for a way to change the text above the form in a same manner as the fields use the progressive profiling.

At the bottom of this page " http://www.pardot.com/faqs/forms/setting-progressive-profiling/ " it says:

*If you would like to have multiple progressive questions per “phase” of the form then use the same logic as designated above for all fields in that “phase”.*

But no further explanation or example is given ( if this even applies to the 'above form' text )

Answer (score 0):

The text above (or below) the form can not be changed by actions in the form. Your best bet to change this text above the form is to use dynamic content, which only works on populated fields for known prospects when the page is loaded. Dynamic content is useless for anonymous visitors..

Multiple questions per 'phase' allows you to have several fields appear after a single selection. For example, you ask for 'delivery' preferences - email, download, mail - and the user selects 'mail' you can have a full contact field set appear.